# Linter or User error: Setting state from useEffect causing loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

Currently my component looks like:

```
const { listOfStuff = [{name:"john"},{name:"smith"}] } = props
const [peopleNames, setPeopleNames] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
  listOfStuff.forEach(userName => {
    setPeopleNames(peopleNames.concat([userName.name]))
  })
},[listOfStuff, peopleNames])
```

As you can probably see this results in an infinite loop, since `peopleNames` is being updated. Since its included in the dependancies array.

Now, I could remove it from the dependencies array. But my linter would yell at me.
And previous experience has told me to trust my linter over my own judgement.

I feel like im missing something fundamental here.

Ideally, I would like the `peopleNames` state to look something like

```
['john','smith']
```

Comment: Aside: Why don't you concat your `peopleNames` before you set the state? Seems silly to do a state update each time for each item in the loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
setPeopleNames(current => current.concat([userName.name]))
```

Then you can remove `peopleNames` from the dependencies array.

The second array item returned from useState ie setState can take a function as it’s argument where the parameter of the function is the current value of the state. So you can make changes based on the current state value without referencing the first argument of useState.

Further homework:

Your useEffect code can be simplified to:

```js
useEffect(() =>
    setPeopleNames(current =>
        current.concat(listOfStuff.map(stuff => stuff.name)
    ),
    [listOfStuff]);
```

Comment: It still loops :/

Comment: Then you can remove peopleNames from the dependencies array.

Comment: I would, but then my linter yells at me.

Comment: It won’t any more ;)

Comment: In fact you MUST remove it for it to work otherwise as you’ve seen you’ll get a loop

Comment: WHAT MAGIC IS THIS?!

Comment: I’ve added an explanation

Comment: Thanks, that totally solved my problem. Ill have to do some research on what you just taught me!

Comment: I’ve added a further simplification FYI